# How to combine 2 files of 2 functions into one file 2 function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 3 files:
1.driver.m to call function Perimeter() in file Perimeter.m and call function Area() in file Area.m
2.Two function files:  Perimeter.m and Area.m

Now I want to combine Perimeter.m and Area.m into one file such as myFunction.m which contains 2 function Perimeter() and Area(). Is this possible in Matlab?

```
function A = Area(x)
   A = pi* x^2;
end
function P = Perimeter(x)
   P = 2*pi*x;
end
% Calculate area and perimeter of circle x
x = 5;
perimeter = Perimeter(x)
area = Area(x)
```

Thank for help

Comment: Possible. Some options are, 1, static method of a class; 2. function with parameter to decide which result to return; 3. array of function handles, etc.

Comment: Typically you’d make one file for each independent function. Tricks mentioned above you should avoid, they complicate things more than simplify them. What you can do is put the functions at the end of `driver.m`. They’ll be local functions only accessible from other code in that file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The simplest way is to use the so-called [nested function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)

```
function [perimeter,area] = main()
function A = Area(x)
    A = pi* x^2;
end
function P = Perimeter(x)
    P = 2*pi*x;
end
% Calculate area and perimeter of circle x
x = 5;
perimeter = Perimeter(x);
area = Area(x);
end
```